# Does the Null Space of a column differ from a row null space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say i have the vectors $\langle 1,1,2\rangle$ and $\langle 2,0,1\rangle$ and find the column space its

$\langle 1,1,2\rangle a + \langle 2,0,1\rangle b = \langle 0,0,0\rangle$ the only value of $a$ and $b$ that can make the zero vector is $\langle 0,0\rangle$ since the vectors are independent so there is no non-trivial nullspaces.

but if I take the row vector of $\langle 1,1,2\rangle$ and $\langle 2,0,1\rangle$ it becomes

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1/2\\
0 & -2 & -3
\end{pmatrix}

and in this case it does have a null vector, $\langle x,y\rangle = \langle 1/2,-3/2 \rangle z.$

so am i missing something or are the null spaces separate?

Comment: Putting the given vectors into a matrix as *columns* is different than putting them in as *rows*. The main reason for this is that you'll use *row* operations on the matrix (this would be the usual, standard method), which will change the columns in one way but change the rows in another.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the "null vector" $\langle1/2, -3/2\rangle z$. Left-multiplying it (as a row vector) to the matrix would give a non-zero row vector for $z\ne 0$. Right-multiplying it (as a column vector) to the $2\times 3$ matrix would not fit.

Answer (score 1):

the maximum number of linearly independent rows (row rank) is equal to the maximum number of linearly independent columns (column rank), that means that you know that for your matrix the columns have to be dependent because you have two independent rows but three columns. That means also that the null spaces cannot have the same dimension.